# Can not install php5-curl on Debian

Tags: curl, debian

I can not install curl. The error message you can see below. When I installed php5-fpm and Nginx, I needed the following line in /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
in deb http://php53.dotdeb.org stable all
```

Not this line is commented out but it looks that the server is using dotdeb.org anyway. How can I solve this problem without uninstalling php5-fpm?

```
srv106:/etc/php5/fpm# apt-get install php5-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-curl : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.3-7+squeeze9) but 5.3.11-1~dotdeb.0 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Answer (score 0):

`php5-curl` needs `php5-common` for squeeze, and that `php5-fpm` needed `php5-common` from dotdeb, it's normal that you can't install it. Have you tried to install `php5-curl` without commenting dotdeb.org in sources.list? Because `php5-curl` is present on these repositories.